# drop_duplicates() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_index'

Tags: duplicates, drop

In my machine, the code can run normally. But in my friend's machine, there is an error about drop_duplicates(). The error type is the same as the title.

Comment: `pip install pandas -U` or `poetry update pandas`

Answer (score 2):

Open your command prompt, type `pip show pandas` to check the current version of your pandas.
If it's lower than 1.0.0 as @paulperry says, then type `pip install --upgrade pandas --user`
(substitute **user** with your windows account name)

Comment: All great, except don't substitute **--user** for anything. That tells it to use the current user. Putting your user name will just confuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Type `import pandas as pd; pd.__version__` and see what version of Pandas you are using and make sure it's >= 1.0 .

Comment: To me the same error happens if I do `df["col_name"].drop_duplicates(keep="first", inplace=False, ignore_index=False)`.
And it works as expected with `df.drop_duplicates("col_name", keep="first", inplace=False, ignore_index=False)`.
That's because pd.Series' version of drop_duplicates doesn't expect ignore_index argument, while pd.DataFrame's one does.
`pd.__version__` is `1.0.5`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as Wzh -- but am running pandas version 1.1.3. So, it was not a version problem.

Ilya Chernov's comment pointed me in the right direction. I needed to extract a list of unique names from a single column in a more complicated DataFrame so that I could use that list in a lookup table. This seems like something others might need to do, so I will expand a bit on Chernov's comment with this example, using the sample csv file "iris.csv" that isavailable on GitHub. The file lists sepal and petal length for a number of iris varieties.  Here we extract the variety names.

```
df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')

# drop duplicates BEFORE extracting the column
names = df.drop_duplicates('variety', inplace=False, ignore_index=True)

# THEN extract the column you want
names = names['variety']
print(names)
```

Here is the output:

```
0        Setosa
1    Versicolor
2     Virginica
Name: variety, dtype: object
```

The key idea here is to get rid of the duplicate variety names while the object is still a DataFrame (without changing the original file), and then extract the one column that is of interest.